# Cassandra HOST ID is empty - Linux

Tags: cassandra-4.0

While checking the nodetool status for cassandra, we get empty HOST ID. How to resolve the empty HOST ID?

I am trying to install cassandra for TWCloud (https://docs.nomagic.com/display/TWCloud2022x/Installing+Apache+Cassandra)

[Missing HOST ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM3ww.png)

## Datacenter: datacenter1

```
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load        Tokens  Owns   **Host ID**     Rack
UN  10.40.226.137  277.93 MiB  256     ?                      rack1

I foresee the Cassandra Session Exception in the linux console.

[Cassandra Session Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvlfr.png)

Cassandra Error:
2024-02-14 17:40:37,250 [main] ERROR com.nomagic.authentication.server.config.CassandraConfig - Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/nomagic/authentication/server/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [com/nomagic/authentication/server/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses 


WebApp Platform Error :
2024-02-14 20:23:26,422 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] ERROR com.nomagic.webappplatform.authentication.internal.authserver.AuthServerAuthenticationService - authorize
com.nomagic.authentication.client.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

For information on error please have look into the attached error screenshot

Cassandra - 4.0.3
```

I tried modifying the cassandra-env.sh file by changing the host name (127.0.0.1).

I am expecting to run the cassandra having HOST ID.